# Swift 4 - URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

I have a small issue when parsing APIs from the website www.adx.ae

Here are the two APIs:

1- List of all public companies: https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/adx/svc/Members.svc/ListedCompanies?showPrivate=false&showPublic=true

2- Detail of each company by its ID:
https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=ADIB

All we have to do is to chance the ID according to each company to get its latest trading price ... etc.

My aim here is to list both the names and each company's trading price in a tableView.

So far here is what I have done

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    func getPrice(company: [Company]) {

        var price = [String]()
        let companyLink = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID="

        for comp in company {
            let link = companyLink + comp.ID

            guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                guard let dataResult = data else { return }

                do {

                    let company = try JSONDecoder().decode(SpecificCompany.self, from: dataResult)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        price.append(String(company.LastTradePrice))
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }).resume()
        }

        print(price)
        allPrices = price

    }

    struct Company: Decodable {
        let Name: String
        let ID: String
        var link: String {
            get {
                return "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID=" + ID
                }
        }

    }

    struct SpecificCompany: Decodable {
        let LastTradePrice: Double
    }

    var allCompanies = [Company]()
    var allPrices = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getCompanies()
    }

    func getCompanies() {

        let link = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/adx/svc/Members.svc/ListedCompanies?showPrivate=false&showPublic=true"

        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return print("Error") }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let obtainedData = data else { return print("No data")}

            do {
                let adx = try JSONDecoder().decode([Company].self, from: obtainedData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.allCompanies = adx
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch {
                print("Nothing")
                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allCompanies.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = allCompanies[indexPath.row].ID
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = allPrices[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the prices in the array that I am looking for. The allCompanies array seems to be empty until the function of cellForRowAt indexPath is called!! Even putting the function getPrice there is not solving the issue.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: `dataTask(with:)` is async. That's something you seem to miss. If you are looking for all of call to complete before reloading the data, use a dispatch_group (with enter, leave and notify).

Comment: @Larme can you provide some example on where it may be applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the controller class, It looks allCompanies array to get how many rows will UITableView has and because It is empty (not 0), It crashes. Change "numberOfRowsInSection" with below code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(allCompanies.count == 0)
    {
        return 0
    }else{
        return allCompanies.count
    }
    }
```

For fetching prices, you are sending allCompanies array to fetchPrice function but you are doing it when It is empty. You can call fetchPrice function after companies are fetched. In addition, print(prices) prints empty array because network requests are async but you are printing without waiting for answer.

```
  func getCompanies() {
    let link = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/adx/svc/Members.svc/ListedCompanies?showPrivate=false&showPublic=true"
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return print("Error") }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let obtainedData = data else { return print("No data")}
        do {
            let adx = try JSONDecoder().decode([Company].self, from: obtainedData)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.allCompanies = adx
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.getPrice(company: self.allCompanies)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Nothing")
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = allCompanies[indexPath.row].ID
    if(allPrices.count != 0 && allPrices.count > indexPath.row){
        cell.textLabel?.text = allPrices[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

EDIT 2: I append string to prices array when everytime request finishes and refresh tableview. Now It overrides, usual text of cell. However, you can write it anywhere you want. This will be better approach rather than waiting for all requests to be finished.

Get price function;

```
var allPrices = [String]()

func getPrice(company: [Company]) {

let companyLink = "https://www.adx.ae/en/_vti_bin/ADX/svc/trading.svc/ListedCompanyOrderBook?listedCompanyID="
for comp in company {
    let link = companyLink + comp.ID
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        guard let dataResult = data else { return }

        do {

            let company = try JSONDecoder().decode(SpecificCompany.self, from: dataResult)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.allPrices.append(String(company.LastTradePrice))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.allPrices)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In addition;
This code will work but I suggest you to write a network layer for this kind of operations and moving them from your controller classes.

Comment: Hi Emre, and thank you for your comment. I don't have an issue displaying the allCompanies, but I can't view their prices using their IDs.

Comment: When do you want to get the prices? After table cell tap?

Comment: It should be immediately after the launch of the app (after ViewDidLoad). However I am not getting anything if I implement getPrice method in the code above

Comment: I added answer for your question. I tried it and can successfully print prices. Please check In addition part also :)

Comment: I tried your edit, but I am not able to get the prices. The print(Price) in getPrice function returns an empty array.

Comment: Yes try to print it inside request. I wrote why it prints empty in answer.

Comment: The same (empty array). I also have associate the getPrice array to var allPrices. I use allPrices to put detailedText for the cell, but no use

Comment: I didn't understand can you please describe what you want to do in more details.

Comment: I want to have the price of each company as a subtitle in each cell. Right now it shows the ID for each company in the title of the cell.

Comment: I have edit what exactly I wanted. I am getting index out of range error, because it is empty.

Comment: I wrote the solution for what you want. It is getting prices and writing to cell. I'm now overriding cell text label but you can write wherever you want. However, don't forget that this whole code isn't a good approach.